# Idempotents and number of proper cyclic codes

Tags: coding-theory, idempotents

So, there was a question on my exam last year as follows:

Using idempotents, determine the number of proper cyclic codes of length 17.

I got the question right, but I can't remember how to do the question. I know I need to

1. Find the classes mod 17 and what's in those classes
2. Determine the corresponding idempotent polynomials (which don't need to be written explicitly)
3. Write the overall idempotent polynomial
4. Determine the number of cyclic codes
5. Determine the proper number of cyclic codes

So, I'm getting hung up on 1 and 5.

Questions:

1. How do I figure out what the "classes" are and what they contain?
2. How do I figure out the proper number of cyclic codes?

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with cyclotomic cosets? And, by the way, can we assume that the codes are supposed to be binary :-)

Comment: I'm not familiar with cyclotomic cosets, but I'll go look that up. Also, yes, it can be assumed that the codes are supposed to be binary.